# How to produce "JSON diff" to be printed in js console?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, karma-jasmine

In my angular project I often need to compare JSONs in my Karma/Jasmine tests and it would be really instrumental to have a console output of what was added and removed in comparison between 2 structures (e.g. these fields added, these changed values and these disappeared)

The format of such output is not important as soon as I can figure our the difference. Perhaps one or few JSONs.

Is there a good way to produce such a difference info?

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take any JS diff library for that. For example: https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff